# How to solve my error with TimerTask and Threading?

Tags: java, android, firebase, web, mobile

I am developing Android app, which is getting clipboard and sends it to database. I am using Android Service and Timer for this task.

My service called "Sending":

```
public class Sending extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent Intent, int startId) {

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new doInTime(getApplicationContex()), 0, 3000);

    }
}
```

My class for TimerTask execution:

```
public class doInTime extends TimerTask {

    Context context;

    public doInTime(Context con) {

        Context = con;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

          new Thread (new Runnable(

              @Override
              public void run () {

                  //getting clipboard and sending to Firebase db.
              }));

     } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }
}
```

While I start service, I am getting Runtime Exception.

Comment: `I am getting Runtime Exception.` share your exception

Comment: what exception you got put the logcat error here.

Comment: You have a typo here: `getApplicationContex()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to start `TimerTask` in `onStartCommand`?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  Timer t = new Timer();
  t.schedule(new doInTime(this), 0, 3000);
  ...
}
```